# How to correctly add TextChangeListener to editText in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

So I tried to use editText as an input for user to write date (from the range of 1900-2200) using editText field which i set to numeric like this:

```kotlin
idData.inputType = InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED or InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER
```

idData is the id of input field. I wanted my app to open an intent(PelniewRoku) with that number as parameter(rok) - so if the number don't fit the restriction I didn't launch the intent, just showing user warning stored in values as "warning".
The code for listener (based on that simple tutorial: https://www.tutorialkart.com/kotlin-android/android-edittext-on-text-change/) goes like this:

```kotlin
[79]  idData.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher 
        {
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?)
            {
            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: Int, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int)
            {
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: Int, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                if (s<2201 and s>1899)
                {
                    var pelnie: Intent = Intent(applicationContext, PelniewRoku::class.java)
                    pelnie.putExtra("algorytm", rodzaj)
                    pelnie.putExtra("rok", s)
                    startActivity(pelnie)
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.warning, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }

        })
```

(I also add number of the starting line of that code to ease finding place of the errors)

After trying to launch it I get the following errors, but they seems rather vague to me (at least in matter what I actually should do):

```
[project and kotlin file path]: (79, 39): Object is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence!, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int): Unit defined in android.text.TextWatcher
```

```
[project and kotlin file path]: (85, 13): 'beforeTextChanged' overrides nothing
```

```
[project and kotlin file path]: (89, 13): 'onTextChanged' overrides nothing
```

```
[project and kotlin file path]:  (90, 34): The integer literal does not conform to the expected type Boolean
```

```
[project and kotlin file path]: (99, 27): None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
public open fun makeText(p0: Context!, p1: CharSequence!, p2: Int): Toast! defined in android.widget.Toast
public open fun makeText(p0: Context!, p1: Int, p2: Int): Toast! defined in android.widget.Toast
```

I do all the imports - at least all suggested by the compiler.

Comment: see the difference between signature of your functions `beforeTextChanged` and `onTextChanged` and the tutorial you linked

Comment: Well, the only difference I see is that in my code s parameter is supposed to be int, and in tutorial it is CharSequence... BUT I NEED IT TO BE INT, especially that android studio don't let me to convert CharSequence to int, and i set the input type of editText widget to integer - what is the data type I need here.

Comment: You can't make it int by force because the abstract class has defined it to be charsequence. To convert charsequence to int, you do something like `s.tostring().toint()`

Comment: Well now I started to feel dumb and asking myself why didn't I thought about double conversion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As sonnet said, you cannot change `onTextChanged()`'s parameter types.

Try it like this:

```
        override fun onTextChanged(string: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            val nullableInt = string.toString().toIntOrNull() // if string cannot be parsed to Int, toIntOrNull() returns null

            if (nullableInt != null && nullableInt < 2201 && nullableInt > 1899)
            {
                var pelnie: Intent = Intent(applicationContext, PelniewRoku::class.java)
                pelnie.putExtra("algorytm", rodzaj)
                pelnie.putExtra("rok", s)
                startActivity(pelnie)
            }
            else if (string.length == 4)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.warning, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, that really help... though it still has some unwanted behavior. I mean my warning message was supposed to be displayed after someone finish to write the date in editText, but it is displayed after every digit he put (I mean when I start to write for example 1935 I get this warning message three times but I wan't supposed to get it at all).

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot!
Though I use >3 instead of ==4 to get also the cases with numbers with more than 4 digits (which of course also aren't the expected input, so they need this message too.)

Comment: Then it would be great if you could accept the answer.